# DVD drive won't work after installing software

Tags: windows-8, dvd

DVD drive was already region-free but for some reason would not play a certain DVD as it was the "wrong region". This is the first time I've played a DVD on the drive, but I've imported a lot of CDs before and they always worked fine, even CDs bought from the USA (I live in the UK).

To get around this, I downloaded a piece of software called "[DVD Region Killer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/CD-DVD-Tools/CD-DVD-Rip-Other-Tools/DVD-Region-Killer.shtml)".

(Clicking the link won't start the download, so go ahead and check it.)

After this, the drive isn't recognised. It won't show up in "My Computer", and when I insert a disc it will start to whir but not take action, i.e. iTunes won't recognise that I have put a CD in.

In the Device Manager, the drive shows up with a caution-sign. The device status reads:

> Windows cannot start this hardware device because its configuration information (in the registry) is incomplete or damaged. (Code 19)

Disabling, uninstalling and reinstalling does not help.

Clearly the software download is the issue, but it is difficult to remove. The only files I can find in Program Files are:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Elaborate Bytes\DVD Region Killer
```

which contains a changelog and a HTML document which has no info on uninstalling.
It doesn't show up on "Add or Remove Programs", or even as a background process when I press ctrl-alt-del.

Apparently it has no interface as such, and can be accessed by an icon in the system tray, (see review in link) but I don't see the icon.

If it helps to know, I have a Dell Inspiron running Windows 8 64-bit, and the model of the DVD drive is:

MATSHITA DVD+-RW UJ8C2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe uninstalling the driver in Device Manager and then allowing it to be installed by Windows solve the problem. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725782.aspx for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it didn't work. I think maybe I need to delete the driver software and then re-download and install it. Where would be the best place to download the software from?

Comment: It's rare for an inbuilt DVD drive to have a special driver (otherwise how would Windows continue it's installation, for instance). Try to uninstall any software that might be conflicting with the DVD drive, uninstall the driver, reboot, reinstall the driver.

Comment: OK that makes sense, so I don't need to download a new driver, only find and remove the conflicting software. The problem though is that it's really difficult to find. I'll have another look tomorrow and see if I can find it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this error by letting Windows install the software for me.

I received a message from the **Action Center** telling me something like `Software needs to be installed to run the drivers`. I let it install, and now the drive works fine.

Problem solved.